# How to compare data from multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to compare some data from different multiple databases, as I have illustrate my current case, I have there databases, database 1 is the main, and time to time database 2 and database 3 are updated from database 1. I have some difficulties to get the final result which return the data from database 1 and two columns column show the availability in database 2 as Yes or No, and the same with second extra column that will indicate the data availability on the database 3 with Yes or NO.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
Select  ID      as  db1_ID,
    First_name  as  db1_First_name,
    Last_name   as  db1_Last_name,
    Email       as  db1_Email,
    Password    as  db1_Password,
    Request_Id  as  db1_Request_Id,
    User_Id     as  db1_User_Id,
    Request_name    as  db1_Request_name
from User 
inner join User_request 
on User_request.User_Id = user.ID
)   AS DB1_VIEW

LEFT OUTER JOIN 

(
Select  ID      as  db2_ID,
    First_name  as  db2_First_name,
    Last_name   as  db2_Last_name,
    Email       as  db2_Email,
    Password    as  db2_Password,
    Request_Id  as  db2_Request_Id,
    User_Id     as  db2_User_Id,
    Request_name    as  db2_Request_name
from User 
inner join User_request 
on User_request.User_Id = user.ID
)   AS DB2_VIEW

ON  db2_ID  = db1_ID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN 

(
Select  ID      as  db3_ID,
    First_name  as  db3_First_name,
    Last_name   as  db3_Last_name,
    Email       as  db3_Email,
    Password    as  db3_Password,
    Request_Id  as  db3_Request_Id,
    User_Id     as  db3_User_Id,
    Request_name    as  db3_Request_name
from User 
inner join User_request 
on User_request.User_Id = user.ID
)   AS DB3_VIEW

ON  db3_ID   = db1_ID
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
           ID   First_name  Last_name   Email   Password    Request_Id  User_Id Request_name
            1   Oliver  Jake    OJake@domain.com    123         1            1   Request1
            2   Mathew  Harry   MHarry@domain.com   123         1            2   Request1
            3   Jacob   Reece   JReece@domain.com   123         1            3 
Request1
            4   Charlie Damian  CDamian@domain.com  123         1            4   Request1
```

Comment: please show your current query

Comment: Are user IDs always the same in all databases? If no, what the condition of equality?

Comment: DDL and DML of your tables and data would be far better received as well. Images of data aren't useful to the rest of us with transcribing and guessing data types. Please supply it in a consumable format; help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your first select statement:

```
SELECT  DB1_VIEW.*
   ,CASE WHEN DB2_VIEW.db2_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Available_db2
,CASE WHEN DB3_VIEW.db3_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Available_db3
```

You can remove all the details apart from the ID fields in the db2_view and db3_view subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query before execute you should use replace [SourceDB]  to your source database and [TargertDB] to your target database. Insert the table name into  #mdtables  to include for comparison.

```
USE [SourceDB] 

IF Object_id('tempdb..#mdTables') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #mdtables; 

CREATE TABLE #mdtables 
  ( 
     id         INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
     schemaname NVARCHAR(128), 
     tablename  NVARCHAR(128) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO #mdtables 
            (schemaname, 
             tablename) 
VALUES      ('dbo', 
             'user'); 

DECLARE @mdTableLim   INT =0, 
        @mdTableRowId INT =0 

SELECT @mdTableLim = Count(*) 
FROM   #mdtables; 

SET @mdTableRowId = 1; 

WHILE @mdTableRowId <= @mdTableLim 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @SDBName   VARCHAR(50) = '[SourceDB]', 
              @TDBName   VARCHAR(50) = '[TargertDB]', 
              @tableName VARCHAR(100) = '' 
      DECLARE @WhereF        VARCHAR(max) ='', 
              @joincondition VARCHAR(max) ='', 
              @or            VARCHAR(10) ='', 
              @select        VARCHAR(max) = '', 
              @comma         VARCHAR(1)='', 
              @query         VARCHAR(max) ='', 
              @and           VARCHAR(5)='', 
              @where1        VARCHAR(1000) ='', 
              @wOR           VARCHAR(5)='' 

      SELECT @tableName = tablename 
      FROM   #mdtables 
      WHERE  id = @mdTableRowId; 

      SELECT @joincondition += Isnull(@and + ( CASE 
                                                 WHEN cu.column_name IS NULL 
                                               THEN 
                                                 NULL 
                                                 ELSE ' src.[' + cu.column_name 
                                                      + 
                                                      '] = ' + 
                                                      'trgt.[' 
                                                      + c.column_name + ']' 
                                               END ), ''), 
             @WhereF += Isnull (@or + ( CASE 
                                          WHEN cu.column_name IS NOT NULL THEN 
                                          NULL 
                                          ELSE Isnull ( '  src.[' + 
                                               TC.column_name 
                                               + 
                                               ']  ', 
                                               ' isnull( src.[' + 
                                               C.column_name + 
                                               '],1)  ' ) 
                                               + Isnull( '<> trgt.[' + 
                                               TC.column_name 
                                               + ']', 
                                               ' = isnull (src.[' 
                                               + 
                                               C.column_name + '],1)  ') 
                                        END ), ''), 
             @or = ( CASE 
                       WHEN cu.column_name IS NOT NULL THEN '' 
                       ELSE ' OR ' 
                     END ), 
             @and = ( CASE 
                        WHEN cu.column_name IS NULL THEN '' 
                        ELSE ' AND ' 
                      END ), 
             @select += @comma + ' src.[' + c.column_name + ']  ' 
                        + Isnull (' , trgt.[' + TC.column_name + ']', ''), 
             @comma = ',', 
             @where1 += Isnull(( @wOR + ( CASE 
                                            WHEN cu.column_name IS NULL THEN 
                                            NULL 
                                            ELSE ' trgt.[' + cu.column_name + 
                                                 '] is null  ' 
                                          END ) ), ''), 
             @wOR = ( CASE 
                        WHEN cu.column_name IS NULL THEN '' 
                        ELSE ' OR ' 
                      END ) 
      FROM   information_schema.columns C 
             LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage CU 
                    ON C.column_name = cu.column_name 
                       AND constraint_name LIKE 'PK_%' 
                       AND c.table_name = cu.table_name 
             LEFT JOIN [TargertDB].information_schema.columns TC 
                    ON C.column_name = TC.column_name 
                       AND c.table_name = TC.table_name 
      WHERE  c.table_name = @tableName 
             --AND columnproperty(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 0    
             AND c.column_name NOT IN ( 'LST_CHG_TMS', 'LST_CHG_TMS', 
                                        'LST_CHG_USR_ID' 
                                        , 
                                        'LST_CHG_USR_ID' ) 
             AND c.data_type NOT IN ( 'image' ) 
      ORDER  BY cu.column_name 

      SET @query = 'select ' + @select + ' from ' + @SDBName + '.dbo.' 
                   + @tableName + ' as src left join  ' + @TDBName 
                   + '.dbo.' + @tableName + ' as trgt on ' 
                   + @joincondition + ' where (' + @where1 + ')' 
                   + Isnull ('and '+ NULLIF (@WhereF, ''), '') 

      DECLARE @qu1 VARCHAR(max) = 
              ' declare @cnt int =0        select @cnt =count (1) from ' 
        + @SDBName + '.dbo.' + @tableName 
        + ' as src left join  ' + @TDBName + '.dbo.' 
        + @tableName + ' as trgt on ' + @joincondition 
        + ' where (' + @where1 + ')' 
        + Isnull (' OR '+ NULLIF (@WhereF, ''), '') 
        + '    if (@cnt>0)       begin     select ''' 
        + @tableName + ''' as [  ],@cnt         ' +-- @query + '    end    ' 

      BEGIN try 
          EXECUTE ( @qu1) 
      END try 

      BEGIN catch 
          PRINT @qu1; 
      END catch 

      SET @mdTableRowId = @mdTableRowId + 1 
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not need CTE's or sub-queries.
A few joins might do it.

```
SELECT
Usr1.ID AS db1_User_Id,
Usr1.First_name AS db1_First_name,
Usr1.Last_name AS db1_Last_name,
Usr1.Email AS db1_Email,
Usr1.Password AS db1_Password,
MAX(UsrReq1.Request_Id) AS db1_Request_Id,
MAX(UsrReq1.Request_name) AS db1_Request_name,
CASE WHEN COUNT(UsrReq2.User_Id) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Available_Db2,
CASE WHEN COUNT(UsrReq3.User_Id) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS Available_Db3
FROM [Database1].[User] AS Usr1
LEFT JOIN [Database1].[User_request] AS UsrReq1 ON UsrReq1.User_Id = Usr1.ID
LEFT JOIN [Database2].[User] AS Usr2 ON Usr2.ID = Usr1.ID
LEFT JOIN [Database2].[User_request] AS UsrReq2 ON UsrReq2.User_Id = Usr2.ID
LEFT JOIN [Database3].[User] AS Usr3 ON Usr3.ID = Usr1.ID
LEFT JOIN [Database3].[User_request] AS UsrReq3 ON UsrReq3.User_Id = Usr3.ID
GROUP BY
Usr1.ID,
Usr1.First_name,
Usr1.Last_name,
Usr1.Email,
Usr1.Password;
```